# Cannot find module '/Users/mymacbook/install'

Tags: mongoose, terminal, installation, node-modules

I am trying to download Mongoose but whenever I do

```
node install mongoose
```

I get the following error on my terminal

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/mymacbook/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:502:3
```

I have tried the methods given in the answers where the global install in not working. Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem here and how to solve it.

Comment: It's `npm install`, not `node install`

Comment: I have no idea how I could make that mistake thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JJJ pointed out, it is **npm** install not **node** install.

Looks like a case of misinterpretation.